# Open/eject DVD using pure Java Code

Tags: java

Is there any possibilites how to open CD/DVD Rom using pure JAVA code? or must be there implementation of  e.g.    `.vbs` script?

Comment: @Nate That link was rather useless, it bounced between ad after ad :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer I thought the code was relatively straight forward... I have ad blocker on sorry bout that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some sample [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0574.html). However, did not test it so do not know if it really works.

Also Windows version probably matters (I assumed you refer to Windows as you have mentioned Visual Basic Script).

Answer (score 2):

No. Java does not provide the abstractions for ejecting the optical media drive. You'll have to find a non-pure Java solution such as what [Tom describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13982104/24396).